# Special unique columns

Tags: mysql, database-design, unique

I have a situation where a website (a source) has multiple feeds (category separated)

```
Feed Table
feed_id | source_id | feed_url
1       |  1        | http://example.com/rss?category=1
2       |  1        | http://example.com/rss?category=5
3       |  2        | http://textample.com/rss

Item Table
item_id | true_id | feed_id
1       | 1332    | 1
2       | 76549   | 1
3       | 76549   | 2
4       | 76549   | 3
```

the true id is the id I try to get from the source site.
I want the item id 2 & 3 are the same, because they share the same source (example.com), item 4 is not the same because it has a different source (textample.com)
Is there a way I can enforce that consistency, without adding the source id to the Item Table?

Comment: Assuming you are saying that in the `Item` table, a `<true_id, feed_id>` pair is unique only if the feeds have different `source_id`. Then I think you would need to add the `source_id` with a `UNIQUE<true_id, source_id>` added, I can't think of a way to cascade a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: That's what I am trying to say, I just felt that adding the source id is kind of redudant, because the `feed_id, source_id` pair is always the same

Comment: Aye, it is.  From a data normalisation point of view.  But your uniqueness constraint is on the `source_id`, not the `feed_id`, whilst still needing to reference the `feed_id` as the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

RUN

```
ALTER TABLE `itemTable` ADD UNIQUE (`feed_id`);
```

Comment: Sorry, that would enforce that item_id 1 and 2 could not share the same feed_id

Comment: first run `ALTER TABLE itemTable DROP INDEX feed_id` then `ALTER TABLE itemTable ADD UNIQUE('feed_id','true_id')`

Comment: Again, it's not related to the feed_id, but the source_id which is referenced in the feed Table. My point was that it seemed redundant to include the source_id as a column in the feed item list, when it is clear that all of one feed have the same id